# Updating field in pytest plugin

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

So I have a custom pytest plugin (which I inherited) and in the init section I have "flag = True". Later, from an external script, I want to change this to "flag = False". Is this possible? And if so, how would I do it?

My initial inclination is to create a set_flag method inside the plugin, but I don't know how to access my plugin from outside. My impression is that the method below (which is in the file, but not part of the class) is called automagically by pytest. Is there a way to access the plugin object which pytest creates? Or could I even just add a parameter to the method found below?

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    api = config.option.api
   if api:
        config.pluginmanager.register(MyPlugin(api,config), "API_Pytest")
```

I've been reading pytest documentation as best I can, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. TIA